# How to make Single Line Horizontally Scolling UITextView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uitextview

From few days I am trying to make an `UITextView` in which the `width` and `height` is `fixed`. And as user Types its content size increases. SO that the Line Doesn't breaks.

It feels to user that he is typing in one line.

And If he scrolls the horizontally then He can scroll the `content` of `UITextView` instead of taping in `UITextView`.

I am using this piece of code to achieve this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
UITextView *txtView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 50)];

txtView.text = @"Hello";
txtView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
txtView.delegate = self;
[txtView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:40]];
txtView.contentSize =txtView.frame.size;
[self.view addSubview:txtView];
}

//Delegate method

  -(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)tView
{

if (tView.text.length > 8) {
    // Set some higher width of the text view content size.
    tView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(200.0f, tView.frame.size.height);
}
}
```

But it does not seem to work. When I reach at the end My cursor shift to Next Line.

I have searched in Google And SO.

Find these Links but they doesn't seems to work.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864188/how-to-make-single-line-textview-scroll-horizontally-only) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555178/how-to-make-a-uitextview-scroll-horizontally-as-the-user-types)

Comment: did u try adding textview to scrollview ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an `UITextView`, but an `UITextField`, with lines set to 1.

Comment: But what if  I type extra content...I want that user swipes horizontally and the content scrolls...How can i do this in `TextField`

Comment: You can try to add an UIGestureRecognizer to the text field to react on swipes

Comment: And how can I scroll content...Gesture recognizer is ok..But how to scroll content :(

Comment: Put the text field in a scrollview, move the content offset when swiping.

Comment: Make an UIScrollView, put the textfield in its content view, change the content view size when it gets larger, change the scroll view's content offset to scroll the scroll view (and thus the text field)

Comment: got your point let me try this one...Once done i will let yo uknow

Comment: I have done it..Bur I am facing a simple issue will you help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97206/discussion-between-theeye-and-rahulmishra).

Answer (score 0):

To make the `UITextView` scroll horizontally, you need to specify its `contentsize` width larger than its frame.

```
    _textView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(500, 20);
```

Also make sure you constraint the `textview` width and height just like you do for a normal `scrollView`.

To limit the number of lines in a textview:

```
      _textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines=1;
```

But if you want to make `textView` one line, then you should use `UITextView` in a `scrollView`. To make it even simpler, use `UITextField` in a `scrollView`.